# create and update timestamp

Tags: django, django-models

Getting errors on migrate. When I don't set any default, i get an error

```
match = datetime_re.match(value) 
TpyeError: expected string or buffer

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I set a default or tried it as `null=True`  or `blank=True`, i get an error `The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present`. Okay, so I should remove it, but then I run into the above error.

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=None)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=None)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: But how can you `auto_now_add` and say that the default is `None` at the same time? `auto_now_add` is in fact a default.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, okay? even if it's timestamp, it's the same thing. I am just googling answers what people did.